# Feynman propagator from Hadamard propagator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, greens-functions, propagator

The Feynman propagator is defined as
$$i G_F = \theta(t-t')G^+ + \theta(t'-t)G^-. \tag{1}$$
Using
$$G^{(1)} = G^+ + G^-,$$
$$G_R = -\theta(t-t')G, $$
$$G_A = \theta(t'-t)G, $$
$$\bar{G} = \frac{1}{2}(G_R + G_A), $$
and
$$iG = G^+ - G^- ,$$
it can be shown that
$$G_F = - \bar{G} - \frac{1}{2}iG^{(1)}. $$
I tried reproducing the calculation and got the following. First note that
$$G_R = i\theta(t-t')G^+ - i\theta(t -t')G^-, $$
and
$$G_A =-i\theta(t'-t)G^+ + i\theta(t' -t)G^-.  $$
Using this, I get
$$G_F = - \bar{G} - \frac{1}{2}iG^{(1)}$$
$$= -\frac{1}{2}(G_R + G_A)- \frac{1}{2}i(G^+ + G^-),$$
$$= -\frac{1}{2}(i\theta(t-t')G^+ - i\theta(t -t')G^- -i\theta(t'-t)G^+ + i\theta(t' -t)G^-) - \frac{1}{2}i(G^+ + G^-)$$
$$ = \frac{-i}{2} ( \theta(t-t') - \theta(t'-t) + 1)G^+  - \frac{i}{2} ( \theta(t'-t) - \theta(t-t') + 1)G^-, $$
thus,
$$ iG_F = \frac{1}{2} ( \theta(t-t') - \theta(t'-t) + 1)G^+  + \frac{1}{2} ( \theta(t'-t) - \theta(t-t') + 1)G^-.$$
Nevertheless, this is not equal to equation (1). Independent of the value of the heaviside function, I'll always get a substraction of $G^+$ and $G^-$. Is there a mistake in my process? Or are my last equation and equation (1) equivalent?

Comment: Which conventions? Which reference? Which page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

$$
\theta(x)+\theta(-x) =1
$$

You will see that they are the same.